# T-SQL, zero sum for no match on join

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, zero

I have two tables, one with all my Branches, and one with all my sales. The sales table also contains a Sales Rep ID, a Branch ID, a month and a year.

I need a query that will return the sum of a specific rep's sales for a year, grouped by branch and month, and the query must return 0 if there has been no sales in a branch for that month. I have the following, which does not return 0 if there are no sales:

```
SELECT
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName,
    SUM(s.InvoiceAmount) AS 'Sales'
FROM 
    Branch b
INNER JOIN
    Sales s ON s.BranchID = b.BranchID
WHERE
    s.Year = 2008
AND
    s.SalesRepID= 11
GROUP BY 
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName
ORDER BY 
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName
```

Comment: Are you missing s.Month from the SELECT list?

Comment: My mistake, yes the s.Month is in the SELECT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add the "missing" data to be able to join it.

```
SELECT
    b.BranchName,
    SUM(ISNULL(s.InvoiceAmount, 0)) AS 'Sales',
    s.Month
FROM 
    Branch b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
        b.BranchID AS BranchID
        , s.SalesRepID AS SalesRepID
        , Months.Month AS Month
        , Years.Year AS Year
        , 0 AS InvoiceAmount
      FROM 
          Sales s
          CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 1 AS Month
            UNION ALL SELECT 2
            UNION ALL SELECT 3
            UNION ALL SELECT 4
            UNION ALL SELECT 5
            UNION ALL SELECT 6
            UNION ALL SELECT 7
            UNION ALL SELECT 8
            UNION ALL SELECT 9
            UNION ALL SELECT 10
            UNION ALL SELECT 11
            UNION ALL SELECT 12
            ) Months
          CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT 2007 AS Year
            UNION ALL SELECT 2008
            UNION ALL SELECT 2009
            ) Years
          CROSS JOIN Branch b
      UNION ALL SELECT 
        s.BranchID AS BranchID
        , s.SalesRepID AS SalesRepID
        , s.Month AS Month
        , s.Year AS Year
        , s.InvoiceAmount AS InvoiceAmount
      FROM Sales s      
    )s ON s.BranchID = b.BranchID    
WHERE
    s.Year = 2008
    AND s.SalesRepID= 11
GROUP BY 
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName
ORDER BY 
    b.BranchName,
    s.Month
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar

Comment: glad to hear I am not alone in the way I interpreted the question. All other answers seem to focus on NULL values in InvoiceAmount. I doubt that is what the OP meant.

Comment: Thanks Lieven, that works (sort of). I now get 0 values for months in which the rep did not have any sales in that branch, but the query as a whole only returns branches where the rep has had sales at some point in the year.

Comment: I have adjusted the query to match your requirement

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do a LEFT JOIN to Sales, so as to return even the reps that do not have any records in the Sales table.

Comment: Left join should add those branches with no sales appear in the final query and the aggregate will then return for them.

Comment: -1 There is a where clause on s.SalesRepId and so a left outer join onto Sales would be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is returning NULL, you can use one of the coalescing methods: `COALESCE(SUM(...), 0)` will return the first non-NULL value in the list...

Comment: Shouldn't the coalesce be inside the sum. Or the sum may sum over NULL values. I beleive that this raises a warning in SQL sever.

Comment: Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the join from inner to left outer and added the ISNULL function for branches with no sales.

```
SELECT

    b.BranchName,
    s.Month,
    SUM(ISNULL(s.InvoiceAmount,0)) AS 'Sales'
FROM 
    Branch b
LEFT JOIN
    Sales s ON s.BranchID = b.BranchID
WHERE
    s.Year = 2008
AND
    s.SalesRepID= 11
GROUP BY 
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName
ORDER BY 
    s.Month,
    b.BranchName
```

Comment: The question asks for sales by month even if there are no sales in a particular month. This query returns results for the whole year.

Comment: This did not change my result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a left join and an isnull to get the sum right:

```
SELECT    b.BranchName
,    SUM(isnull(s.InvoiceAmount, 0)) AS 'Sales'
FROM     Branch b
LEFT JOIN    Sales s ON s.BranchID = b.BranchID 
GROUP BY     s.Month,    b.BranchName
ORDER BY     s.Month,    b.BranchName
```

You still need to do some more work with it to get the months showing too if a salesman has no sales in a particular month.